# can anyone explain me why my grid is offset in XY graph?

Tags: xy-pic

So I'm trying to making a simple tree like graph in XY-pic, but it is very strangely shifted: [image]. The shift is strange as from a guide I've found that & signs are used only when there are still non empty columns ahead, but despite doing it in accordance with the example I cant achieve same result. I'm aware that its most likely something very common, but I only recently started with LaTeX and not sure what to try.

On the screen I've shown the issues: root node is shifted to the right, and the leaf node s as well. Arrow from root node seem to be stuck and point towards that very node.

Below is the snippet (Center and math environments are in accordance to the guide, as it says it cant be centered without):

```latex
\begin{center}
    \begin{math}

%        .  |   |   |and|   |   |
%        .  =====================
%        .  |   |or |   | or|   |
%        .  =====================
%        .  | p | n |   | n | q |
%        .  =====================
%        .  |   | r |   | s |   |
%        .  =====================
%        .  |   |   |   |   |   |
%        .  =====================
%        .  |   |   |   |   |   |
%        .  =====================
%        .  |   |   |   |   |   |
%        .  =====================
%        .  |   |   |   |   |   |
%        .  =====================
%        .  |   |   |   |   |   |
%        .  =====================


    \scalebox{}{%
        \xymatrix{
            &  & \node{\land} \ar[dl] \ar[dr] \\
            & \node{\lor} \ar[d] \ar[dl]   &   \node{\lor} \ar[d] \ar[dr] \\
            \node{p}  &   \node{\neg} \ar[d]   &   \node{\neg} \ar[d]  &   \node{q} \\
            & \node{r} &  & \node{s} \\
        }
    }

    \end{math}
    \end{center}
```

Comment: Please, make a compilable example: we can't know how you define `\node` that's not a standard command for `\xymatrix`.

Comment: @egreg sorry I missed the fact that node is a custom command, I work from template our teachers gave us. That actually solved the other half of the problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving alone the fact that `\node` is an unknown command, you have the last arrow in the first row pointing `dr` instead of `d`; in the last row you have an excess `&` token.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\newcommand{\node}[1]{#1} % dummy definition to show the working

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{
         &                            & \node{\land} \ar[dl] \ar[d] \\
         & \node{\lor} \ar[d] \ar[dl] & \node{\lor}  \ar[d]  \ar[dr] \\
\node{p} & \node{\neg} \ar[d]         & \node{\neg}  \ar[d]          & \node{q} \\
         & \node{r}                   & \node{s} \\
}

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure what `\begin{math}` and `\end{math}` are doing, because they're not needed; moreover, blank lines are not allowed in `math`. Also `\scalebox{}{...}` is an error.

[image]

Note `cmtip` to get decent looking arrow tips (the default ones are awful).